# Magnitude of centrifugal force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, harmonic-oscillator, centrifugal-force

> A pendulum is designed for use on a gravity-free spacecraft. The pendulum consists of a mass at the end of a rod of length $l$. The pivot at the other end of the rod is forced to move in a circle of radius $R$ with angular frequency $ω$. Let $θ$ be the angle the rod makes with the radial direction. Show this system behaves exactly like a pendulum of length $l$ in a uniform gravitational field $g = ωR^2$. That is, show that $θ(t)$ is a solution for one system if and only if it is for the other.

I was confused by how to work this problem in a rotating frame. The solution read that the centrifugal force on the mass should be of magnitude $mwR^2$. However, I thought it would be $mwL^2$ where L is the distance between the mass and the center of the circle (**L** = ***l*** + ***R***). What am I missing here?